# How to setup ahmedkhalf/project.nvim so that recent files for project are displayed by default?

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

There is this [code](https://github.com/ahmedkhalf/project.nvim/blob/8c6bad7d22eef1b71144b401c9f74ed01526a4fb/lua/telescope/_extensions/projects.lua#LL167C1-L169C10)

```lua
local on_project_selected = function()
  find_project_files(prompt_bufnr)
end
```

But I do not know how to change it to `recent_project_files`.

I am using LazyVim.